# what is this leading 0 when i print dictionary in bash?

Tags: dictionary

#### Get all node IP and Port numbers

```
   node_ip_port=$(ringsh supervisor ringStatus DATA |grep "Node:"|awk '{print $3}' |awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $1, $2}')
   echo ${!node_ip_port[*]}$'\n'
   for port in "${!node_ip_port[@]}"; do
       echo "$port ${node_ip_port[$port]}"
   done
```

my output

```
0

0 172.16.254.101 8084
172.16.254.101 8085
172.16.254.101 8086
172.16.254.101 8087
172.16.254.101 8088
172.16.254.101 8089
172.16.254.102 8084
172.16.254.102 8085
172.16.254.102 8086
172.16.254.102 8087
172.16.254.102 8088
172.16.254.102 8089
172.16.254.103 8084
172.16.254.103 8085
172.16.254.103 8086
172.16.254.103 8087
172.16.254.103 8088
172.16.254.103 8089
172.16.254.104 8084
172.16.254.104 8085
172.16.254.104 8086
172.16.254.104 8087
172.16.254.104 8088
172.16.254.104 8089
172.16.254.105 8084
172.16.254.105 8085
172.16.254.105 8086
172.16.254.105 8087
172.16.254.105 8088
172.16.254.105 8089
172.16.254.106 8084
172.16.254.106 8085
172.16.254.106 8086
172.16.254.106 8087
172.16.254.106 8088
172.16.254.106 8089
```

Comment: add some description what is the issue? how expected output is different from the current output

Comment: Both echo statements have a "0"  where is this zero coming from ? i expected the ouptut i got without the zero. Thank you. Also thx for editing my post not good at this site at all. @deadshot.

Comment: `node_ip_port` is not an array.  It is a string.

Comment: I figured it out in the for loop $port is the indice so i took it out of the echo and now things look normal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error, first I have an array of size one with a string in it, so that is one problem. Then the `"0"` was printing the index of the array without even knowing it. Back to the drawing board, case closed.